# Selenium find element by name not working

Tags: selenium, extjs

I am trying to automate ExtJs application. The field ID changes when ever there is a new code change on the Page. When i'm trying to find it by NAME, selenium is not finding it but by using ID it works. Since the ID changes with every code release, i need to find it by NAME.

**Code that works:**

```
findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='textField-1947-inputEl']"))`
```

**Codes that does not work:**

```
findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='type']"))
```

and

```
findElement(By.name("type"))
```

Webpage:

```html
<input id="textField-1947-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text" autocomplete="off" name="type" tabindex="14" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" style="width: 100%;" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

If your script not report `Element Not Found` or `NoSuchElement` exception, it means your script find multiple elements but the first one is not you wanted.

If not report above exception, try add some sleep before find, if sleep can work, change to use `wait` api.

Try the xpath `//input[@name='type']` on page manually in browser's DevTool to see it can find how many elements and the first one is your wanted or not.

If all above still can't resolve your problem, check this element is inside frame or not, if so, please switch to the frame before operate it.

Comment: I have used wait API but it times out trying find this element after 30 seconds. I have tried xpath `//input[@name='type']` in **Try Xpath** Firefox extension and it identifies correctly.

Comment: Check the element inside frame or not

Comment: If find by ID works but not by name, then it's not likely a frame problem, either.  Does your "Try Xpath" extension show when there are multiple hits?  I'm thinking with the original poster that it matches more than one element.

Comment: @BillHileman You were right. There were two hits. I have modified the xpath as `//input[@name='type'])[2]` and it works.

Thanks Bill and Yong for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There were two hits with the xpath so resolved the issue by accessing second instance of match as `//input[@name='type'])[2]`.